# How to change id multiple times by clicking button multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to change shapes by clicking on the button on web page .So for that I I made multiple id's so for every click of the button current id gets changed into another id and shape changes. every id has properties of a particular shape.

```js
var shapeBtn = document.getElementById("cng_shape");

shapeBtn.onclick = () => {
    if (document.getElementById("shape").id == "shape") {
        document.getElementById("shape").id = "shape1";
        // document.getElementById("shape").setAttribute("id","shape1");
        //
    } else if (document.getElementById("shape1").id == "shape1") {
        document.getElementById("shape1").setAttribute("id", "shape3");
    } else if (document.getElementById("shape3").id == "shape3") {
        document.getElementById("shape3").setAttribute("id", "shape");
    }
};
```

I tried using if statements and check whether the current id is true and it its true change its id to new one.

Comment: what is issue, is above code not working

Comment: Yea the above code is not working

Answer (score 3):

try below code , also need to check if id is exist like below,

```js
var shapeBtn = document.getElementById("cng_shape");

shapeBtn.onclick = () => {
     
    if ( document.getElementById("shape") && document.getElementById("shape").id == "shape") {
        document.getElementById("shape").id = "shape1";
        // document.getElementById("shape").setAttribute("id","shape1");
        //
    } else if ( document.getElementById("shape1") && document.getElementById("shape1").id == "shape1") {
        document.getElementById("shape1").setAttribute("id", "shape3");
    } else if ( document.getElementById("shape3") &&  document.getElementById("shape3").id == "shape3") {
        document.getElementById("shape3").setAttribute("id", "shape");
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="shape">test</div>
<input type="button" id="cng_shape" value="click" />
```

Comment: Yes the code is working now . can you explain what you did and how its working?

Comment: 1) check if id is exist  2) with this if id is exist then id is name as "shape" --- so this condition will check both if satisfy then goes into if condition